# How to change values inside IQueryable (not database)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

**Question:** How to change values inside IQueryable? (dont change inside database)

`Query` has data from database.

```
IQueryable<My_Model> Query = from x in _context.My_DbSet
                              select x;
my_List = await Query.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

Inside `Query`, I want to change some values. for example: if `name` is empty than display `"Missing Name"`.

If location is `"NYC"` than display `"NEW York City"`

**Database table / Model class**

```
|------|----------|
| Name | Location | 
|------|----------|
| Dave | NYC      |
|------|----------|
|      | NYC      |
|------|----------|
| Bob  | LA       |
|------|----------|
```

Comment: Which version of EF are you using? EF Core?

Comment: FYI, `Query` does not contain *any data at all*. What it does contain is an *expression tree that is waiting to be translated to SQL and then executed*. The actual translation & execution only happens if and when you call an execution method on it such as `Query.ToList()` or `await Query.ToListAsync()`, and the result of such a call is a `List` that contains data.

Comment: @PeterB I didnt knew that, Thanks for letting me know

Comment: @GuruStron using Core

Comment: @dave then selecting as in provided answer should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code applies case when on the sql side instead of you while fetching data

```
_context.My_DbSet.Select(x => new My_DbSet
{
  Name = x.Name ?? "Missing Name"
});
```

old EF :)

```
(from data in _context.My_DbSet
                         select new My_DbSet
                         {
                             Name = data.Name ?? "Missing Name"
                         }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this will work in old EF, hence the comment to the question.

Comment: Does not see the difference. As far as I remember old EF had problems with `new SomeEntity` in the `Select`.

Comment: try as anonymous

Comment: I know that it can be work around with anonymous object. But you are not using anonymous object for old EF. Also OP uses EF Core so that part can be just deleted.